# função JavaScript Bloqueia todos os campos input's

Tags: javascript

preciso de uma ajuda, eu montei uma função para bloquear o espaço seja teclado no primeiro elemento do input

gostaria de fazer com que a função rodasse em todos os campos, porem ele só bloqueia no primeiro campo os demais campos a função não funciona.

```js
var input = document.querySelector('input');
    
  input.addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
    if (this.selectionStart === 0) {
        if (e.which === 32 ) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="campo1">
  <input type="text" id="campo2">
  <input type="text" id="campo3">
```

Comment: `querySelector` só retorna um elemento; se precisa todos use `querySelectorAll`.

Comment: quando uso o querySelectorAll a função nao funciona em nenhum campo

Comment: Sim, leia a documentação dessa função para entender como ela funciona: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usando o `querySelector`, você estará aplicando a regra apenas ao primeiro elemento encontrado no DOM.

Pegue todos os elementos utilizando a função [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)  que retornará um array com todos os elementos selecionados, depois basta apenas percorrer esses elementos e aplicar a regra para o bloqueio do caracter.

```js
let input = document.querySelectorAll('input');

//console.log(input)

    input.forEach(el => {
      el.addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
          if (this.selectionStart === 0) {
              if (e.which === 32 ) {
                  e.preventDefault();
              }
          }
      });
    })
```

```html
<input type="text" id="campo1">
  <input type="text" id="campo2">
  <input type="text" id="campo3">
```

Comment: muito obrigado , pela ajuda...